# Multiple $_POST variable in a variable

Tags: php, forms, post

Hey I have this code that sends an email with some data sent by a form:

```
<?php

  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    error_reporting(E_NOTICE);

    function valid_email ($str) {
      return ( ! preg_match("/^([a-z0-9\+_\-]+)(\.[a-z0-9\+_\-]+)*@([a-z0-9\-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,6}$/ix", $str)) ? FALSE : TRUE;
    }

    if ($_POST['name'] != '' &&  $_POST['email'] != '' && $_POST['tel'] != '' && valid_email($_POST['email']) == TRUE && strlen($_POST['comment']) > 1) {

      $to = preg_replace("([\r\n])", "", $_POST['receiver']);
      $from = preg_replace("([\r\n])", "", $_POST['name']);
      $subject = 'Online Message';
      $message = $_POST['comment'];
      $match = "/(bcc:|cc:|content\-type:)/i";
      if (preg_match($match, $to) || preg_match($match, $from) || preg_match($match, $message) || preg_match($match, $subject)) {
        die("Header injection detected.");
      }

      $headers = "From: \"".$_POST['name']."\" <".$_POST['email'].">\n";
      $headers .= "Reply-to: ".$_POST['email']."\r\n";

      if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
        echo 1; //SUCCESS
      } else {
        echo 2; //FAILURE - server failure
      }

    } else {
      echo 3; //FAILURE - not valid email
    }

  } else {
    die("Direct access not allowed!");
  }
```

I want to add the `$_POST['tel']` to the `$message` variable so in the body of the email I can get the message plus the telephone that people type into the form. In the first part of the code I think I made the telephone input obligatory.

I tried doing `$message = $_POST['comment'] && $_POST['tel'];` but the only thing I recieve is a `1` in the body of the mail that is the first number of the telephone entered.

Comment: I'd recommend you improve your indentation - this isn't the most readable code. Also the line starting `if($_POST['name']!=''` could do with being broken up - try setting a margin line in your IDE at 80 to 100 characters (certainly no more than the latter) and break up statements either by wrapping or using intermediate assignments. This eliminates horizontal scrolling when editing, and also when posting to S/O `;-)`

Comment: `preg_replace()` just to strip new lines? In fact there's a lot of unnecessary regexes in your code, often `str_replace()`/`strpos()` and friends will do the job much more efficiently, advice which is littered throughout the docs for PCRE in the PHP manual. And if you want to validate an email address, try [`filter_var()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$message = 'Comment: ' . $_POST['comment'] . ' Tel: ' . $_POST['tel'];`

Comment: Thanks but if I want a break line between the two fields?

Answer (score 1):

&& means AND (the logical version) so you're actually getting "true".

Use the period, ., to concotenate strings.

```
$str = 'Hello'.' world'; print $str;
```

Outputs Hello world

Comment: So it would be: `$message = $_POST['comment'] . $_POST['tel'];` ?

Comment: Yep. Might want to put something like a space between, and also, you could optionally use sprintf.

$message = sprintf('Comment: %s, Phone: %s', $_POST['comment'], $_POST['tel'] );

Comment: Great! The sprintf worked perfectly. Just one question, can I make a line break between the comment and the phone so it more readable?

Comment: $message = sprintf("Comment: %s\nPhone: %s", $_POST['comment'], $_POST['tel'] );

Comment: Yeah but I added some fields like name etc so now it's like `$message = sprintf('Name: %s, Comment: %s, Phone: %s', $_POST['name'], $_POST['comment'], $_POST['tel'] );` so when I add the \n doesnt work

Comment: You gotta use double-quotes. PHP adds the newline any time it encounters a \n inside double-quotes.